# Prevent sbt release from generating jar/dom files

Tags: sbt, release

I did configure my `sbt.build` to generate a zip file when publishing my app (thanks to sbt-release). However, it is still generating a dom/jar files and I don't see any parameters I could tweak to prevent this (it seems to be the default behavior, see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html). Any idea how could I turn that off ?